# Do you know a good REGEX lib for C Language?

Tags: c, regex

I've found two libs to work with Regular Expression in Ansi C:

**[Lightweight C++]**
http://students.ceid.upatras.gr/~sxanth/lwc/
This is not really a Regexp lib but I can use it to write my expressions on it and then execute the preprocessor to get the generated C code.

**[Real Regex Lib]**
http://www.osix.net/modules/article/?id=349
But I didn't find much references about it.

So, is there anybody here using it? Do you know any other lib?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

There are POSIX regular expressions (regex.h):

http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: these are not reall regular expression - PCRE is the answer

Comment: I often use POSIX as a fall back if pcre is not available, but only when built on a POSIX machine :) I think the OP wants something portable.

Answer (score 4):

Many projects are using [libpcre](http://www.pcre.org/).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pcre.org/

Perl Compatible - so if that's bad, I guess it's a non starter.  BSD license, Wikipedia page - reasonable man page entry.